# data not defined d3 for object type

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am modifying an interactive chart made by Matthew Weber (link [here](http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518#index.html)) and I keep running into the error that my data is not defined when I'm trying to create a unique key to bind the data to the graph. I keep getting the error

```
TypeError: data is undefined
```

I think the problem stems from the fact that I'm using numeric values (age) as the x axis as opposed to a parsed date from his example, but I can't figure out what to change in order to fix it.

I have also declared the data variable in a couple of lines above it and d3 seems not to recognize it.

My code is below.

Code snippet: (the error occurs starting with "color.domain")

```
        var menu = d3.select("#menu select")
    .on("change", change);    

//suck in the data, store it in a value called formatted, run the redraw function
// *****
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
                                    formatted = data;
                                    redraw();
                                  });

d3.select(window)
    .on("keydown", function() { altKey = d3.event.altKey; })
    .on("keyup", function() { altKey = false; });
var altKey;

// set terms of transition that will take place
// when a new economic indicator is chosen   
function change() {
  d3.transition()
      .duration(altKey ? 7500 : 1500)
      .each(redraw);
}

// all the meat goes in the redraw function
function redraw() { 

    // create data nests based on economic indicator (series)
    // *****
    var nested = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.dma; })
        .map(formatted)

    // get value from menu selection
    // the option values are set in HTML and correspond
    //to the [type] value we used to nest the data  
    var series = menu.property("value");

    // only retrieve data from the selected series, using the nest we just created
    var data = nested[series];

    // for object constancy we will need to set "keys", one for each type of data (column name) exclude all others.
    // *****
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return (key !== "age" && key !== "dma"); }));
    // *****
    var linedata = color.domain().map(function(name) {
                    return {name: name,
                            values: data.map(function(d) {
                            return {name:name, age: d.age, value: parseFloat(d[name],10)};
                            })
                    };
    });
```

Comment: Can you verify that `nested` and `series` are actually defined with expected values/properties?  Since you're reporting `data is undefined` exception, that means `data` has no value being set to it.

Comment: Can you show a couple of line from your CSV file?

Comment: @David, A couple of lines from my data are as followed (data is comma delimited)

`age, dma, model1, model2, model3, model4

18,  FT. MYERS-NAPLES DMA (EST.), 0.095,0.425, 0.371, 0.152

18, JACKSONVILLE DMA (EST.), 0.043, 0.409, 0.386, 0.132

18, MIAMI DMA (EST.), 0.041, 0.452, 0.359, 0.182`

Comment: @Jason Did I not define the data with nested[series];? Before the redraw function, I wrapped my data around the d3.csv function. I've edited my post to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your `d3.csv` call is succeeding?  You're not checking to make sure that it doesn't throw an error, so it's worth checking to make sure it's getting loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks @BenLyall, I'm fairly new to D3 and js, how would I ensure the data is loaded correctly? From my understanding, all I need is set the file name as the parameter as shown above? Another way I know for pulling in the data is constructing the function like  `data.forEach(function(d) { d.age = +d.age;});` Do you know if the redraw function will work

Comment: Do you know how to debug JS code in a browser?  As in opening up Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug?

Comment: Yes, but to be honest I'm not comfortable since I'm new to js. But right now I'm running the debug with a code break at the color domain. Prior to that line, the data variable was an array with a length of 868, which matches my data set. However, when I step forward, something got in the way and "erased" it. Thoughts?

Comment: An example would help to work things out.  Can you post a link to your page/code?  Looking at the example `csv` file you posted in a previous comment, it doesn't seem to match your code.  In the `color.domain` you're filtering out `type` and `date`, but these don't seem to be a part of your `csv` data.  Perhaps you haven't completely converted the example you posted to match your dataset?  I would guess that you haven't updated the `html` of the page (specifically the `#menu select` element) to match your data either.

Comment: @BenLyall, sorry about that, it was just an oversight when copying and pasting. I've updated my post to reflect my code. As suggested, I created a repository for you to take a look at my code [here](https://github.com/minh5/d3-example). Any tips would greatly be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the line with:

```
var data = nested[series];
```

`series` is set to `turnout`, since that is what your `#menu select` element has as it's default value.

I think that you probably want to make the following changes...

Change

```
<p id="menu" class="menuchoice">Select series: <select>
<option value="turnout">Model 1</option>
 <option value="unsure">Model 2</option>
<option value="fiscal">Model 3</option>
 <option value="social">Model 4</option>
```

to:

```
<p id="menu" class="menuchoice">Select series: <select>
<option value="dma1">DMA 1</option>
<option value="dma2">DMA 2</option>
<option value="dma3">DMA 3</option>
<option value="dma4">DMA 4</option>
<option value="dma5">DMA 5</option>
<option value="dma6">DMA 6</option>
<option value="dma7">DMA 7</option>
<option value="dma8">DMA 8</option>
<option value="dma9">DMA 9</option>

</select>
```

And you will get something displayed.  Not sure if that's all you're looking for.  This is what I suspected in my comment when I said " I would guess that you haven't updated the `html` of the page (specifically the `#menu select` element) to match your data either. "

It's possible that you wanted this the other way around, with your "Select series:" combo box being `[Model1, Model2, Model3, Model4]` and your chart having 9 lines with `dma1` through `dma9`, but from your code it looks like you intended it the way I've done it.

If it's the other way around, you're going to have to change your `nested` parameters and update the `html` for the `#menu select` element again.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll look into it! Quick question, if I wanted to change the `nested` and update the html for the `#menu select` element, what other arguments could I pass through it?

Comment: to update the `select` element, just change the `html`.  If you want to update the nest so instead of nesting by `dma` you're nesting by model, then you will probably need to change your initial data structure in the function callback for the `d3.csv` call.  ie. `formatted` would need to change, so that each entry in the array accounts for only a single model, rather than all 4 like you've currently got.